# Why do return seem to cause trouble in objc define macro

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macros, c-preprocessor

I have been searching for answers, but my key-word-fu is just plain failing me.

I have an macro I am using in objc/Xcode:

```
#define strongify(source, target) __strong typeof(source) target = source; if(target == nil) NSLog(@"variable was already nil")
```

which leads to me to quite often needing to write code like so:

```
strongify(weakSelf, strongSelf);
if (!strongSelf) return;
```

So I thought that I would expand on that macro with the following:

```
#define strongifyOrReturn(source, target) __strong typeof(source) target = source; if(target == nil) return
```

Xcode is refusing to autocomplete it and complains it doesn't know it when compiling.

How ever, if I don't use the return keyword and just NSLog something out still using the same macro name, Xcode will happily do as I ask and the new name is listed in the autocompletion suggestions.

I am hoping that some of you can tell why this is so...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, my Xcode happily autocompletes that macro. (That does not mean that *I* would be happy with this macro :-)

Comment: What is the error gives by the xCode ?

Comment: @ThilinaCháminHewagama It was giving me an error like 'Implicit declaration of function 'strongifyOrReturn' is invalid in C99'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone else with a similar problem, should try to see if they are being foobar'ed by Xcode. After my MBP got an overnight hibernation it now autocompletes and compiles and is generally happy.

So the lesson to take away from this, restart Xcode and re-test before you post a question on SO. Sigh.